# API JSON response using POST in PHP

Tags: php, rest, api, post, https

I have an API resources push.php which I am using for mobile application which requires the application to POST data in order to get response. Now the mobile applications are completed and now i am working on the website of the same application. Rather than writing the code again i would like to use the API calls i've created which resides on the same server.

My registration form resides on the root folder (root/index.php)
My API call for registration resides in API folder (root/API/push.php)
I want to send form data using POST and retrieve the JSON data from push.php successfully. Issue is in between the starred comments.

**ROOT/index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Register User</h2>
    <form name="signup" method="post" action="signup.php">
        <center><img src="images/logo.png" width="150"></center>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
    </form>
    <h1>
        <?php
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                    $output = NULL;
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $username = $_POST['password'];

                    //********************************************
                    //Send values to API and receive output in JSON

                    $JSON = getResponseFromAPIbyPOST($username, $password);

                    //********************************************

                    $output = json_decode($JSON);
                    if ($output->response == "SUCCESS") {
                        echo "Registration Successful!";
                    } else {
                        echo "Registration Failed!";
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**ROOT/API/push.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'includes/dbcon.class.php';
$dbcon = new dbcon;
$conn = $dbcon->connect();
// Set Action
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
} else {
    $action = NULL;
}
// Check if API call is valid
if ($action == "register") {
    $output = new stdClass();
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dbuser(vuser,vpass) VALUES ('{$username}','{$password}') ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $output->data = "USER_CREATED";
            $output->response = "SUCCESS";
            echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } else {
            $output->data = "SQL Error $conn->errno : $conn->error";
            $output->response = "FAIL";
            echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    } else {
        $output->data = "INVALID_ARGUMENTS";
        $output->response = "FAIL";
        echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
} else {
    $output->data = "INVALID";
    $output->response = "FAIL";
    echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    "data": "USER_CREATED",
    "response": "SUCCESS"
}
```

if you look at index.php between the starred comments, I am trying to figure out what function can i use here >> **getResponseFromAPIbyPOST($username,$password)** which will get me the response and save it tovariable $JSON.

**What is the correct php function to achieve this goal?**

*Server is using HTTPS*

Comment: In short, either [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [get_file_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). You have some sql injection problems as well; read about parameterized queries.  They are supported by mysqli.  Also, good job using an object to represent your json and consider using a concrete class instead of stdClass so that people can understand the output by just looking at the classes.  It also allows you to override [jsonSerialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) and do cool things.

Comment: That is very insightful and quite helpful @AlexBarker. For the sake of a short example i didnt write the prepared statement here. Also i've created separate class for output. This was merely a short example because my previous question for rejected for lack of examples. Question: Can i post data using get_file_contents? currently im using get_file_contents to write a log to a txt file so i got a hang of it. Curl seems to be thing what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `curl` or `get_file_contents`.

using **cURL**

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.yourdomain.com/api/push.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query([
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password
]));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```